# Confused about the brackets in this loop

Tags: java, brackets

This is the question in Coding bat(the Java version):: 
**Given an array of ints, return true if the array contains a 2 next to a 2 somewhere.
    has22({1, 2, 2}) → true
    has22({1, 2, 1, 2}) → false
    has22({2, 1, 2}) → false**

This was my solution:

```
public boolean has22(int[] nums) {

  for (int i=0; i<nums.length-1;i++) {

     if (nums[i]==2 && nums[i+1]==2) {
         return true;
     }
     else {

        return false;
     } 
  }
}
```

Doesn't compile while this does..

```
public boolean has22(int[] nums) {

  for (int i=0; i<nums.length-1;i++) {

     if (nums[i]==2 && nums[i+1]==2) {
         return true;
     }
     else {

     } 
  }    
    return false;

}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm confused about the brackets at the end.

Comment: What about if the condition of the for loop is not satisfied at the first iteration ? Does your method return a value ? Something like `for (int i=nums.length-1; i<nums.length-1;i++)` for example.

Comment: Make sure that `i+1` doesn't go beyond the length of your `nums` array. You can check this by seeing where you are in your current iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a case when your argument is empty or `null`. Your first method doesn't compile, because it doesn't return a `boolean` value for **all** cases.

Your second method compiles, because it will return a `boolean` value in any case, after the iteration is complete.

Comment: So basically the else is redundant?

Comment: @JerryMurphy in this specific case the `else` is redundant.

Comment: I understand now...adding the else confused me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
  public boolean has22(int[] nums) 
     {
      for (int i=0; i<nums.length-1;i++) 
       if (nums[i]==2 && nums[i+1]==2) 
         return true;  
       return false;
     }
```

You can write your program like above no need of braces.
for each conditional statement one statement is always there if we want to associate more than one statement with any conditional statement then we provide {} braces for example
        if(some condition)
         stmt1;
no need of braces but if more than one statement then
      if(some condition)
       {
         stmt1;
         stmt2;
       }

so always remember more than one statement braces compulsory and to avoid problem when ever open a bracket just close at the same time and write inside that one it will let you some relax. 
Thanks 
asif aftab